# Inaccurate results while multiplying numbers on chrome console

Tags: javascript

Multiplying a number (0.55) with (10**18) results an extra 60 added to the result. While multiplying it in 2 different numbers results accurate as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179)

Comment: Please post your code